# How to achieve staggering divs?

Tags: html, css, sass

I've been dealing with a problem, that I cannot seem to find an answer for. Basically, I have a set of divs, all of the same class, but varying in size depending on the data displayed in them. I'm trying to get them to stagger in a certain way. (excuse my bad drawings)

edit: almost forgot to mention, the divs are using the bootstrap class "col-lg-6".

This is the original result: 
[original effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FQnn.jpg)

The result I was able to achieve:
[achieved effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsi1N.jpg)

And the desired result I am trying to achieve:
[desired effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a52ac.jpg)

The css styling I used to achieve the current result is as follows:

```
.div_class {
   position: relative;
   vertical-align: top;
   text-align: center;
   display: inline-block;
   margin-top: 10px;
}
```

How could I achieve the desired effect?

Thanks!

Comment: You're looking for a masonry layout, if you have just these three static divs then you can just create a two columns layout. otherwise, you can use [CSS Grid](https://medium.com/@andybarefoot/a-masonry-style-layout-using-css-grid-8c663d355ebb) or a JS plugin like [masonry.js](https://masonry.desandro.com/)

Comment: That is precisely what I'm looking for. Thanks for the point in the right direction! Going to look into it right now.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use a table to create this effect. Make sure you use the padding within the cells to create the spacing that you need... Hope this helps

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
<tbody>
<tr style="height:45%;">
<td style="height: 150px; width: 98px;">Div 1</td>
<td style="height: 225px; width: 118px;" rowspan="3">Div 3</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 47px;">
<td style="height: 150px; width: 98px;" rowspan="2">Div 2;</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```